# Doing an action after inserting a row in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers, row

I want to write a code in android that when a row inserted(trigger) in my database(sqlite)
I do an action
what should I do?

```
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
             this.connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                 public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                     String message2;
                     Message message = (Message) packet;
                     if (message.getBody() != null) {
                          message2=message.getBody();
                       String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                      .getFrom());

////////////////////////////////////                         
                      SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
                         try{
       ContextWrapper cw =new ContextWrapper(thisact);
       String path =cw.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/electronic.db3";

       checkDB =  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE) ; 


             String[] partsss = message.getBody().split("/"); 
       //if message from server is setting                  

             ContentValues values = new ContentValues();    

             values.put("message", message.getBody());
             values.put("do",0);
             checkDB.insert("Messages",null ,values);
```

}
  this is my code it is like chat code  , i want when a message recieved and inserted to database I do an action in another class.
in fact I want a listener for inserting in database.

Comment: what have to tried so far?

Comment: Show me your data inserting method. and constructor of the DatabaseHelperClass.

Comment: What do you really want? After a row has been inserted, what do you want to do?

Comment: I want when a row inserted (I dont know when insert) , immediately  I show a message  and I say a row inserted  , ( like sql dependency ).

Comment: Okay.Then show how you insert a record into the database.Let's see it.

Comment: please see my post again , I edited it

Comment: after you `checkDB.insert("Messages", null, value);` make a Toast, and then add code to close your database

Comment: because of some reasons I can not show  my message here(in this class) , I want to do this(showing message) in another class

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your code for inserting a Student record into the SQLite database:

```
public void insertRecord(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
       SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put("Name", queryValues.get("name"));   
        database.insert("student", null, values);

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
           "Record inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //<-You can place it here
        database.close(); 
}
```

As per your other question about what you should do, it all depends on the design of your app.for example, in my student app,after inserting record into database, I could show a list of students with this new record inserted.

Comment: Thank u ojonugwa ochalifu ,but I wanted when a row inserted in database ,an event occer ,and i write a toast message(like trigger) –

Comment: I dont know when my database update  , i want when an row insert immidately I show a message like sql dependency

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the code of Toast message inside of the insert method (where you are inserting the new data).

As database handler is not pointing to an activity/context so you have to pass the context of the parent class while creating DbHandler object.
Like below:

```
Dbhandler dbHandler = new Dbhandler(getApplicationContext());
```

and in your dbHandler class create a constructor like below:

```
public Dbhandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    c = context;
}
```

then the toast message should be declared as:

```
Toast.makeText(c,"data has been inserted! ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here 1st parameter "c" is the context that we have passed to the constructor.